# How to reference JSONSchema object in other JSONSchema object on the same file

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have this problem, I want to create two JSONSchemas and used as a reference on other schema on the same file. e.g.

```
const schema1{
type: 'object',
properties:{
id: {type: 'string'},
name: {type: 'string'}
}
} 

const schema2:{
type: 'object',
properties:{
attributes: {$ref: schema1}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't files; those are two entirely separate data structures.

You can read about references here: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#ref